# How can I control other application in my phone

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am a beginner in programming Android applications in Java. I want to know how to control or change something, for example, cut off the Internet on another application. Is there a way or suggestion. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible unless you are the developer of both and remove the permission for both apps, see: [Can an app give its permission to another application in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529535/can-an-app-give-its-permission-to-another-application-in-android)